# Tomcat memory usage

Tags: tomcat, memory-usage

I'm running tomcat on a ubuntu 10.4 VPS with 512MB of RAM (1024 burstable). I'm using it for development, so performance isn't an issue, but memory is.

Tomcat is currently using about 250MB without any apps installed (I compared memory usage with tomcat stopped and running), and I also need to run lighttpd and mysql.

Is there any way to get that number down? I don't need it to be able to handle a large number of requests at once.

Comment: Try looking in your config files, there might be a setting buried in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try tuning the following parameters on your tomcat startup

-Xms128m -Xmx128m

Also it would be worth you checking on what Garbage collection options you have enabled on tomcat, having GC tuned correctly will help keep your memory usage down.